# Conditionally rename cells in Excel

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet of 5000 rows. One of those rows contains image names. The format of these image names varies but what I want to do is check to see if that image name contains the string 'front' and begins with 'alt-'. If it does, I want to change the prefix from "alt-" to "main-". Is this possible?

So for example:

```
alt-brand-product-name-colour-front.jpg  << Rename "alt-" to "main-"
alt-brand-product-name-diffcolour-front.jpg  << Rename "alt-" to "main-"
alt-brand-product-name-colour-back.jpg
alt-brand-product-name-colour-side.jpg
alt-brand-product-name-reallylongcolour-front.jpg  << Rename "alt-" to "main-"
```

Any help massively appreciated :-)

Comment: hint: `FIND()` , `IF()`, `ISERROR()`. Try!

Comment: Have you tried anything? The above can be achieved using Excel formulas. Would you like to give it a try?

Comment: Hi Shivan, thanks for your response. I don't know Excel well enough, otherwise I would. Thanks for the starting point. How would I would I replace the given text if the condition is true? Thanks! :)

Comment: @RJB: The answer explains it well. Hope you can spend more time on Excel formula documentations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to use the formula below. If "front" is found then it will replace all occurances of "alt" with "main". If "front" is not found then the original string will be left as it is. Cell A1 represents your original filename.

`=IF(ISERR(FIND("front",A1)),A1,SUBSTITUTE(A1,"alt","main"))`

Comment: Phil Applegate, I salute you!